# Disable underlyingFragment when Drawer is opened

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-fragmentactivity, drawer

**Hey,**

In my app I have a Drawer. When it's open the editText from the underlying fragment still works. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

[image]

At the red arrow is an editText that shouldn't respond right now, when the Drawer is opened.

x

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way is to just hide the keyboard then the drawer opens. The only way to get the keyboard showing again is to click the edittext.

Here is one way to hide it:

```
fun hideKeyboard(activity: Activity) {
    val imm = activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    //Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.
    var view: View? = activity.currentFocus
    //If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window token from it
    if (view == null) {
        view = View(activity)
    }
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
}
```